# How to declare an alias for a parameter of a controller action in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

My example:

```
    public IActionResult Search(string query)
    {
        return Index();
    }
```

I would like to use "q" as a parameter as well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to add one more parameter with a default value and check it to see which one to use.

```
public ActionResult Search(string query="",string q="")
{               
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        q = query;
    }
    //do something with q now.
    return View();
}
```

This will work for `Search?query=java` and `Search?q=java`

Comment: It would but it is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

A chap called Jeffery Palermo has built a NuGet package named ActionParameterAlias which should do exactly what you need: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ActionParameterAlias/

Comment: Aha, apologies. I'm not well-versed on the differences yet :(